# Running non-static method with a string as parameters

Tags: c#, methods

I use `s.Keyboard.Keypress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_H);` method. And I want to be able to swap that `VK_H` value to other characters of "Test" we are running. I am using `InputSimulation` library.

So in the test it would run series of input like:

```
s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_T);
s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_E);
s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_S);
s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_T);
```

My code is

```
InputSimulator s = new InputSimulator();

char[] word = "Test".ToCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i<word.Length; i++)
{
    s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_H);
}
```

Comment: I'd use a switch statement for each char in the word, and then execute the appropriate command.

Comment: But I need it for user input.

Comment: Yep, so switch for each letter? Seems pretty straight forward, I'm sure one of these other clever guys will have a slicker solution, but that's my suggestion..not like there are a lot of letters.

Comment: Ok thank you! I still want to see if someone can come up with a shorter solution.

Comment: @mobinblack You should always aim for readability and simplicity rather than shortness. It gets you further. (Of corse it is great if the simplest solution is the shortest - it just so happens that this is often not the case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot think of a scenario where I (as a Reviewer) would let C# code pass that relies on the **name** of an enum record. The records in an enum should be considered as "**Names for numbers**" and simply help you as a programmer to recognize numbers.

Using something like `VirtualKeyCode.VK_T.ToString()` is often used but should be avoided in my opinion (Let's leave logging and debug purpose out of the way for now). I understand that it's a super simple way of getting a text out of that value, but **it is ugly**. Now to your question. I would use this:

```
    InputSimulator s = new InputSimulator();

    foreach(var c in "test")
    {
       VirtualKeyCode keyCode;

       switch(c) 
       {
          case 't':
             keyCode = VirtualKeyCode.VK_T; //Used twice in the text "test"
             return;
          case 'e':
             keyCode = VirtualKeyCode.VK_E;
             return;
          case 's':
             keyCode = VirtualKeyCode.VK_S;
             return;
          default:
             throw new NotImplementedException($"The following character has not been implemented correctly: {c}");
       }

       //Go ahead and use keyCode here
   }
```

Comment: Thats pretty much the same answer as Trey but thanks for the code!